# Sorting Google Maps places by number of reviews

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

When using Google Maps to decide on places to visit, I find that the *total number* of reviews is as helpful in my deciding which places to visit as the place's actual average rating.

However, while Google Maps has some (limited, and awkwardly-implemented) support to restrict searches based on rating, namely filtering places below a certain average rating, it does not have any option to sort places based on how many reviews they have, i.e. obtain a list of the most "popular" places in a given town.

Could anyone possibly suggest a workaround to achieve such search results, or perhaps an external implementation that can, such as an API?

Comment: This is a [very long-standing, popular feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/35820858) that Google is aware of, but not implemented yet. You can follow the issue on their Public Issue Tracker to get updates and show more interest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this site can sort by number of reviews: https://www.top-rated.online/

Answer (score 2):

I created a Chrome Extension that is doing it live on top of Google Maps - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-maps-sorter/okomdlgdhdhoclopfhbfidhnlifmbpbp

This extension adds the sorting button on the bottom right part. To use it:

- Search for what you want.
- Scroll down through the search results to fetch as many results as you want. This is because the sorting happens only on the client side.
- Click on the sorting button and go back to the top.